# Location Invariance not achieved in CNN in spite of 99% test accuracy

Tags: neural-networks, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I have been trying to decode a captcha using CNN. 
The number of training samples is 1,82,000.
 So far, I could achieve 99% accuracy on training as well as test set.
The issue however is that LOCATION INVARIANCE is not achieved while training. The captcha text if slightly shifted horizontally gives bad prediction.
Below image is one of the samples on which network was trained and gives good prediction accuracy for similar images (Accuracy~99%) .
 [image]

But if following image is given , it gives some random prediction.
[image]

The only difference between above two images is location of captcha text.
As far as I know, the usp of CNN is the fact that location of a pattern doesnt matter. So what could be the possible reasons for this ?